# Billing/quota issue when use google cloud api

Tags: text-to-speech, gcloud

I got this error from google cloud though I enabled billing and set quota for text-to-speech already, anyone can help me?

[image]
[image]

Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the texttospeech.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you misread the guidance.

The response says that you may not authenticate using (your) end-user credentials (i.e. something@gmail.com or your email address for some Google Apps domain).

Rather you must authenticate using a Google [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts).

I assume (!?) that the Text-to-Speech service is most commonly used by software and it is not intended to be used directly by humans.

The best solution is to create a service account and use Application Default Credentials to run code as this account. The guidance offers an alternative (works but not ideal) of using `gcloud auth activate-service-account`:

See:

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Comment: I actually ran `activate-service-account` but issue still there
`Activated service account credentials for: [admin-72@xyz.iam.gserviceaccount.com]`

Comment: Right but that authenticates `gcloud` not your code. Please try running your code after exporting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/key.json`.

Comment: @DazWilkin still not working